# Over what points is the fibre under the projection to the affine line of a hypersurface $ X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} \times \mathbb{A}^{1} $ singular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

One page 144 of "Basic Algebraic Geometry I" by Shafarevich, we see:

> Assume $ \operatorname{char}k \neq 2, $ and consider the hypersurface $ X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} \times \mathbb{A}^{1} $ defined by the equation $ \sum_{i,j=0}^{n} a_{ij}(t)\xi_{i}\xi_{j} = 0, $ where $ a_{ij}(t) \in k[\mathbb{A}^{1}] = k[t], $ and the projection $ X \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{1} $ is induced by the projection $ \mathbb{P}^{n} \times \mathbb{A}^{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{1}. $ This is called a pencil of quadrics, with discriminant $ \operatorname{det}|a_{ij}(t)| $ denoted by $ D(t). $
>
> Set $ F = \sum a_{ij}(t)\xi_{i}\xi_{j}. $ If $ D(\alpha) \neq 0 $ at a point $ t = \alpha $ then the equations $ \partial F/\partial \xi_{i} = 0 $ for $ i = 0,\dots,n $ and $ t = \alpha $ have only the solution $ 0, $ so that the points of the fibre over $ t = \alpha $ are nonsingular both as points of $ X $ and as points of the fibre.

I'm having two difficulties with this.

(1) I don't know why the characteristic of this field needs to be other than 2.

(2) I'm struggling to see why the points of the fibre over $ t = \alpha $ are nonsingular. At first, I thought it was an application of the second Bertini theorem, but it's not because the theorem requires(among other things) a field of characteristic $ 0. $ Then I thought it was due to this lemma:

> Lemma: If $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ is a regular map of varieties, *where $ X $ is nonsingular*. The fibre $ f^{-1}(y) $ is nonsingular if $ d_{x}f: T_{x}X \rightarrow T_{y}Y $ is surjective for all points $ x \in f^{-1}(y). $

(Italicized text indicates an addition on my part)

I don't think this lemma is the cause either, since this section of the text is trying to establish when the hypersurface $ X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} \times \mathbb{A}^{1} $ (and the fibres) is nonsingular.